# how can i write a Command that displays the mac address and that each address is followed by a newline?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I try to find a line command that display mac adresse
I think i have to use "inconfig"
but i don't know how to use it ?

> ifconfig | grep "ether" | sed 's/(.*)ether //g'

but it doesn't work

Comment: ifconfig | grep "ether" | sed 's/.*ether \([^ ]*\).*/\1/g'

Answer (score 0):

ifconfig -a|grep HWaddr|sed -n -e 's/^.*HWaddr //p'

result:
00:50:56:9F:66:A4